# Sqlite on Azure with Django database locked

Tags: django, sqlite, azure-web-app-service

I've got a django app that I'm interested in publishing to the Azure App Service. I'm using sqlite because it'll work for this application, my database settings look like this:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': '/home/site/wwwroot/db.sqlite',
    }
}
```

this seems to be the 'right place' to put a database in the App Service so that it persists through deployments.

Unfortunately my post build action

```
  - name: Set migration command on App Service
    uses: Azure/appservice-settings@v1
    with:  
      app-name: 'example-app'
      app-settings-json: '[{ "name": "DISABLE_COLLECTSTATIC", "value": "true" }, { "name": "POST_BUILD_COMMAND",  "value": "python manage.py makemigrations && python manage.py migrate" }, { "name": "SCM_DO_BUILD_DURING_DEPLOYMENT", "value": "true" }]'
```

Runs into trouble because when it tries to migrate for the very first time:

```
Executing post-build command...
No changes detected
Operations to perform:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  Apply all migrations: admin, auth, calculator, conf, contenttypes
  File "/tmp/8db81f47570a6b0/antenv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 306, in _commit
Running migrations:
    return self.connection.commit()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
sqlite3.OperationalError: database is locked
```

I've seen suggestions that this is because of the way the storage is mounted - can I change that?

I don't know how to debug from here.

Answer (score 0):

I tried deploying a [**Sample Django app**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/quickstart-python?tabs=django,windows,azure-cli,vscode-deploy,deploy-instructions-azportal,terminal-bash,deploy-instructions-zip-azcli) that used `Sqlite engine` to Azure Web app and the deployment was successful.

**settings.py:-**

```py
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}
```

[image]

> "sqlite3.OperationalError: database is locked,"

Error occurs when there are multiple connections being done to the database. In order to resolve this error, Switch to other databases like [**PostgreSQL**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/tutorial-python-postgresql-app?tabs=flask,windows) or SQL server. ***One option is to increase the timeout and add check_same_thread to false setting in your **settings.py**.***

```py
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
        'OPTIONS': {
        'timeout': 60, 
        'check_same_thread': False, 
        'uri': True,
      },
   }
}
```

I suggest using Databases like SQL, Postgresql, Mysql which have their host running locally or on Azure.

Comment: Thx. What is BASE_DIR in your settings.py?
I can deploy to Azure and it works but the database gets destroyed each time I deploy which is a deal breaker. The problem is trying to keep the sqlite db in the /home directory (or some other persistent location). Can you help?